# bash get just ms from ping command

Tags: bash

how can I get just ping response time without any prefixes etc

What I'm doing right now, but it returns time=56.7 and I need just 56.7

```
timeinms=$(ping -c 1 $ipaddress | grep 'time' | awk '{print $7}')
echo $timeinms
```

Comment: Use the `split()` function to split `time=56.7` at the `=` character, then print the second field. Or use a regular expression replace function to replace `time=` with an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the PCRE option of GNU `grep`:

```
timeinms=$(ping -c 1 $ipaddress | grep -oP 'time=\K\S+')
```

Here we search for `time=` in a line and if it is found then match is reset due to `\K` directive and we print text until next whitespace.

**Alternative** solution using `sed`:

```
timeinms=$(ping -c 1 $ipaddress | sed -nE 's/.*time=([0-9.]+).*/\1/p')
```